# SSL for local dmain

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx

I have a project in Laravel. It was downloaded from a server to make some modifications. I have a SSL certificate for local domain (`syworkx.local`) from `nginx`. Can somebody help me with the installation and setting up the certificate

Comment: Do not use `.local` for your names, it will only lead to problems, as `.local` is reserver for mDNS. Do not pick any arbitrary TLD either. Register a domain name for real and then use it as suffix for all your naming needs.

Comment: With `.dev` also doesn't work. I have no idea what could be the problem. Maybe I can give you online access via team viewer. Than you can see everything and find the problem. Somebody told me I had to install old version of xampp and php.

Comment: Like said in previous comment: DO NOT pick any abritrary TLD either. `.dev` is specifically bad since it exists for real, and it has HSTS preloading so you will only get problems. Except of course if you register a true `.dev` domain by going through some registrar and then (and only then) use it (your whole new domain, not just `.dev`) as suffix for all your names

Comment: I have this `http://e-papiere.rickimnet2.local` and it works. At the moment I am connected via `localhost:3000` but all the time I have to delete 's' from https. Everything is works very good online, but I have problem with offline version.

Comment: `http://e-papiere.rickimnet2.local/login` is a different project.

Comment: As far as I know .local can be used safely as long as you're locally testing. Anyway, I can look at your issue using AnyDesk. But I don't know how this goes against SO policy.

Comment: It is no problem. Later I will change the pass for teamviewer. Where can I send you access to my computer?

Comment: I make a new certificate `syworkx.kfzpix` but all the time is problem.

Comment: jubayerarefin on Skype

Comment: I sent you info by skype. Martin

Comment: nginx also doesn't want to start

Comment: Problem solved by moving the certificates into the XAMPP and changed the certificate names.

Comment: Yes, he is clever and solved my problem. Good work. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add an existing certificate to your nginx config file as shown below

```
listen 443 ssl;
server_name syworkx.local;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/syworkx_local.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/syworkx_local.key;
```